# How to debug "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range in Swift"

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem with a Swift code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.detailTextLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.1)
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.2)
    }

    // Load feed iamge.
    let url = NSURL(string:feedImgs[indexPath.row] as! String) //** The problem - Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range**
    let data = NSData(contentsOf:url! as URL)
    var image = UIImage(data:data! as Data)
    image = resizeImage(image: image!, toTheSize: CGSize(width: 80, height: 80))
    let cellImageLayer: CALayer?  = cell.imageView?.layer
    cellImageLayer!.cornerRadius = 35
    cellImageLayer!.masksToBounds = true
    cell.imageView?.image = image
    cell.textLabel?.text = (myFeed.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).object(forKey: "title") as? String
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = (myFeed.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).object(forKey: "pubDate") as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white

    return cell
}
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: check myFeed and feedImgs array count, both must be same

Comment: So it is saying that your "feedImgs" array's count is less than the indexPath.row, you should debug the feedImgs array.

Comment: Check the number of elements in `feedImgs` array.

Answer (score 4):

You are accessing two arrays in `cellForRowAt indexPath` method, first is `feedImgs` and second is `myFeed`.

If both array count is same then it will not crash, if both array counts are different then it will crash for `Index Out of range` for one of the array.

For example, `feedImgs` have **4** objects in it and `myFeed` have **5** objects then it will crash at 4th index in `feedImgs` array and give you the reason `Index Out of range`.

Hope this helps to you.

Comment: you can suggest the solution using one array?

Answer (score 0):

Index out of range mean that you need to get index from array where index  greater than array items

so you use index in three places check them

```
let url = NSURL(string:feedImgs[indexPath.row] as! String)
```

,

```
cell.textLabel?.text = (myFeed.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).object(forKey: "title") as? String
```

and

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = (myFeed.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).object(forKey: "pubDate") as? String
```

**So to avoid this issue** Make is safe with if condition

```
(if indexPath.row <  feedImgs.count{
  let url = NSURL(string:feedImgs[indexPath.row] as! String)
}

 (if indexPath.row <  myFeed.count){
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = (myFeed.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).object(forKey: "pubDate") as? String

cell.textLabel?.text = (myFeed.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).object(forKey: "title") as? String

  }
```